# After rename app folder and namespace artisan make shows Exception: Unable to detect application namespace

Tags: laravel, namespaces, laravel-artisan

I've renamed my app folder to aplicativo and changed the namespace to aplicativo. Everything works but artisan make commands.

I changed namespace through composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
        "aplicativo\\": "aplicativo/",          
}
```

Plus command:

```
artisan app:name aplicativo
```

Comment: Laravel has a function to handle changing of the namespace from `App` to (in your case) `aplicativo`; `php artisan app:name aplicativo`; did you use that command, or did you do it manually? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation for more information.

Comment: I used the function.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that Laravel has now added support for custom App path. You can override the App path by adding the following code in `bootstrap/app.php` (or provider).

```php
/*...*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

// override the app path since we move the app folder to somewhere else
$app->useAppPath($app->basePath('src'));
```

Similarly, you can change other paths (database, language, storage, etc.). You can find all the available methods [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L354).

Answer (score 0):

You won't get this to work. You can rename the namespace (as you did with the command), but you can't rename the directory because it's hardcoded as `app`.

You can see the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L292) here.

Comment: Answer from @sunxyw works for me... I'm using Laravel 10

Answer (score 0):

Then... if your using composer try this command

```
composer dump-autoload
```